# Are there any reccomended styleguides or quick reference sheets for VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have been writing VHDL for a short time now, so I feel this is a good time to start making sure my coding is in a good style. I have had trouble finding any good style guides or quick ref. sheets for this. I am thinking of something like the Barr group embedded C standard, but for VHDL.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Style is imposed organizationally and has little bearing on functionality other than restrictions imposed on recognizing constructs eligible for synthesis (IEEE  Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis (withdrawn), and vendor extensions or restrictions). In VHDL syntax there are requirements for separators and delimiters otherwise format effectors signifying an end of line are not needed, there is no input line length limit (and you could always use block comments see IEEE Std 1076-2008 15. Lexical elements). Style isn't dictated by the VHDL standard or any example code therein.

Comment: I somewhat disagree with the notion that it has little bearing on functionality, as code written in bad style increases the chances of bugs and reduces readability. So even though it should synthesize to the same HW it would make a difference in the development process.

Comment: Style isn't addressed by the standard. IEEE Std 1076-2008 1.3 Structure and terminology of this standard "This standard is organized into clauses, each of which focuses on some particular area of the language. Within each clause, individual constructs or concepts are discussed in each subclause. Each subclause describing a specific construct begins with an introductory paragraph. Next, the syntax of the construct is described using one or more grammatical productions. A set of paragraphs describing the meaning and restrictions of the construct in narrative form then follow."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following style is recommended by CERN BE-CO-HT

```
i_   Input signal 
o_   Output signal 
s_   signal
c_   Constant 
g_   Generic  
t_   User-Defined Type
```

There are many other recommendations. You can have a look at coding style followed in CERN BE-CO-HT https://ohwr.org/project/vhdl-style/blob/master/doc/vhdl-coding-style.adoc